# Keras incompatible shapes NN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, shapes, incompatibility

So I have this neural network and I am feeding examples "X" and labels "Y" whose shapes are:

```
X.shape = (10,10,2)
Y.shape = (10,10,2)
```

The code for the model looks like:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from convert import process
import numpy as np

X, Y, rate = process('songs/song1.wav')

X = np.array(X[:10])
Y = np.array(Y[:10])

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=2)
```

Now for some reason once I run this i get the error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 2) and (None, 20) are incompatible
```

I am confused because I fed it data where each example of both "X" and "Y" have shapes (10, 2). So why is it saying that I passed it (None, 10, 2) and (None, 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last layer uses `linear` activation whereas you choose `categorical_crossentropy` loss. Set either

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activations='softmax'))
....loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

or,

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20))
....loss='mse')
```

Also check your data shape, especially the label (`y`).